# Access from within AppDelegate the initial view that NavigationController points to

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I am using Swift 4 and I am wondering how to access from within AppDelegate the initial view that my NavigationController in storyboard points to. In this case my initial view that it points to is HotSpotRISViewController. I need my HotSpotRISViewController instance from within AppDelegate so that I can pass a url variable to it. My storyboard looks like this:
[image]

How do I access my hotSpotRISViewController instance from within AppDelegate? I know about delegation and how it works, and I understand that AppDelegate starts up the app in the first place and can be used for all sorts of important events such as when the app leaves the foreground or opening up a text file externally. But I can't do anything with these events if I don't have any way of accessing the instance of my current view which in this case needs to be HotSpotRISViewController (which again, is the initial view that my NavigationController points to). I am guessing I use the window property somehow. Thank you in advance to anyone that can answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after hours of working things out I solved it. Take a look inside my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if let hotSpotRISViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers[0] as? HotSpotRISViewController {
        hotSpotRISViewController.setURL(theURL: url)
    }
}
```

or you can do it this way, which I assume is the preferred way:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if let hotSpotRISViewController = app.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers[0] as? HotSpotRISViewController {
        hotSpotRISViewController.setURL(theURL: url)
    }
}
```

The difference is that instead of using UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, you use app.keyWindow, which seems better since app is the singleton of your app and is being passed in as an argument in this function.

Hopefully from this example anyone else out there having this problem can get a good idea of what it takes to find the correct ViewController. Don't forget to cast it to your subclass of ViewController, otherwise you won't be able to use any of the functions you made in there.